# How to execute Transact-SQL functions

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How can we execute Transact-SQL functions using JAVA.

Transact-SQL function :

```
SELECT SUSER_ID('sa');
```

We have to execute the above statement using java. Can we achieve this using JAVA ?

Thanks for your responses.
Hi, I'm trying like below, getting "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '{' " Error when I'm using below.

```
     String loginName = "domain\\geethap";
     String selectQuery = "{ EXEC SUSER_SID(?) }";

    CallableStatement cs = connection.prepareCall(selectQuery);
    cs.setNString(1, loginName);
    cs.registerOutParameter(1,java.sql.Types.VARBINARY);
    cs.execute();

    ResultSet resSet = cs.getResultSet();
logger.error("** got resultset **");    
    while(resSet.next()){
        byte[] result = resSet.getBytes(1);
        log.error("ByteSet"+result.length);
        log.error("** ResultSet object:"+result);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

use a callable statement:

```
String loginName = "domain\\geethap";
String selectQuery = "EXEC SUSER_ID ?";

CallableStatement cs = connection.prepareCall(selectQuery);
cs.setNString(1, loginName);
cs.registerOutParameter(1,java.sql.Types.VARBINARY);
cs.execute();

ResultSet resSet = cs.getResultSet();
logger.error("** got resultset **");    
while(resSet.next()){
    byte[] result = resSet.getBytes(1);
    log.error("ByteSet"+result.length);
    log.error("** ResultSet object:"+result);
}
```